# How to move objects in required direction?

Tags: android

My required directions are:

[image]
I've seen from droidz activity example and also from rockpaperscissors example about how to move images in different directions either by using hand or when colliding with walls.

Issue1:

Now I want to move four different images in four directions as shown above. And when they touch the wall up, they should disappear and start again from the starting point one after other and again follow the same direction.

Issue2:

When any of these are touched when moving, either it should disappear and shouldn't continue to loop for that image only or it should take to another activity. 
Please help me with these two issues. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This a very usefull tutorial : http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html
You'll find a full working example at the 7th part.

Comment: @StephaneMathis thanks for the quick reply. I'll surely check it out. Hope my problem gets solved with that.

Comment: Take a look at andengine, cocos2d or any other 2D framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can use these function available in API 11

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setTranslationX(200);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setTranslationY(300);
```

**update**
Try this code sample code.

```
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                tv.setTranslationX(tv.getTranslationX()+10);
                tv.setTranslationY(tv.getTranslationY()+10);
                tv.invalidate();

            }
        });

        }
    }, 1000 , 1000);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

**Update**

To implement the thing that you have shown in the picture. Here is brief description to implement that

- Make a path arrays (A 2D array of points) for each view on which the

  views will travel
- Create a timers for each view with repeat interval of 100 ms or less
  as required.
- In those timers get a point from that path array and pass it to your
  view.
- Loop on that path for ever means in circular way.
- set a `onClck()` Listener of that view.
- In that listener cancel() the corresponding timer for that view and
  destroy that view or set the visibility to GONE.

That all by implementing this you can do this task easily.

Comment: then what about the onclick functionality for infinite loop...??

Comment: why you are using infinite loop.

Comment: coz it is something like game... i want to move them from top to bottom continously until they are clicked....

Comment: Brother it is a timer that will repeat it self after every 1000 ms seconds. And it is just example how you can move views in layout not the full code :) of course you have to create a path to get the movement as you want.

Comment: brother, can you help me in creating as above path, atleast blueprint?